# JavaScript How to make a count up timer with slowdown speed

Tags: javascript, timer, counter

I want to make a count up timer in my page.
It will set a target number and start from 0 to count up.
But I want to it with a slow down speed.
Start high speed, more and more slow to target number.
I can't find a good way or library to do this animate.
Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `setInterval(function, delay)`?

Comment: You need to use an "algorithm", and if you're updating the content of an element, I would recommend using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout` - it has the benefit of an "time" argument that you can use in an algorithm to calculate the value to be displayed, also using requestAnimationFrame would update the value at most 60 times a second, there's no need to update the value more often than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setInterval` for this job, like below:

```
var counted = 0;
var target = 10; // 10 seconds
document.write("Counted : 0");
var i = setInterval(function () {
    if (counted <= target) {
        counted++;
        document.write("Counted : " + counted);
    } else {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Hope this works, I haven't tested it.

Comment: this will count at (almost) exactly 1 per second - the question asks for a counter that "slows down" as it reaches the target